# Is it possible to open a tab or something on chrome using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I already know how to open chrome, but I do not know how to open a specific page from the URL. I'm using python 3.6

Comment: What do you mean by "a specific page from the URL"? Are you talking about a *webpage*? If so, doesn't the URL identify which page you want to open?

Comment: It might be helpful to see the code you are using to open chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To open a webpage in your default browser:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796343")
```

To open a webpage in a new tab in Chrome:

```
import webbrowser

chrome_controller = webbrowser.get(using="chromium-browser")
chrome_controller.open_new_tab("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796343")
```

If this doesn't work for you, there are alternative values of the `using` parameter. Check the [module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html).